# Setting up a virtual/local test server in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio

I am creating a windows service and I would like to be able to debug my code easier. So my plan is to create a web app that will allow me to write and test code and then copy it over to the service.

Is there anyway to set up a virtual or test server similar to XAMPP or WAMP in visual studio?

Comment: There is the cassini web server, or you can simply host it in IIS?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58wxa9w5%28VS.80%29.aspx it looks like this is what I am after

Comment: After you confirm that that was really an answer come back here and answer your own question, and mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far on all of the services I have worked on does a very small ammount of the actual work (usually some sort of timer or file watcher) and the rest of the work is done in seperate classes which allows for easy swapping of .dll files.

a windows form app is very similar to a service and can be used to run code in a way similar to what how the service can.